# Prime Ideals: $ab\:\in \:I$ such that $a\:\in \:I\:\:\vee \:\:b\in I$ vs. either $a\:\in \:I\:$ or $b\:\in \:I\:$ but not both?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Everywhere I read it's "a is element of I or b is element of I", but I couldn't find an explanation if it's a mathematical or (so that it can be the case that a is element of I and b is element of I), or if it's a language or (so that it's impossible that both belong to I)

Comment: In mathematics, “or” is *always* understood to be the “inclusive or”: one, or the other, or both. The “exclusive or”, “one, or the other, but *not* both” is never assumed and always explicitly stated that way. This is stated in the context of mathematics, so it is definitely, absolutely, no question about it meant to be the inclusive or.

Comment: P.S. Please include all information in the *body* of your post. The post does not start at the subject line, just like a letter doesn’t start on the envelope.

Comment: So how can I make "catchy titles" in StackExchange? Because as far as I'm accustomed to from reddit a topic with a "dull" title won't be even answered, but maybe here's another mentality

Comment: So if "or" is to be understood mathematically then what sense does it make to define a prime ideal in the first place? As it's basically the same definition as of an ideal?

Comment: The ideal $I=4\mathbb{Z}$ is NOT prime in $\mathbb{Z}$.  $4 = 2 \cdot 2 \in I$ yet $2 \notin I$.

Comment: The title is fine. But the information should be in the body of the post as well. The post should be self-contained, and not rely on people reading the title first.

Comment: It is not the same definition as an ideal. In an ideal, the condition is that *if* $a$ is in $I$, then for every $r$ you have both $ra$ and $ar$ in $I$. That is: if one of the factors is in the ideal, then the product is in the ideal. For a prime ideal, it is the *converse*: if a product is in the ideal **then** one of the factors has to be in the ideal.

Comment: Why is 4Z not prime? Because I can create elements from 4Z out of elements which do not belong to 4Z? Could you maybe name an example?

Comment: $2$ is not in $4\mathbb{Z}$; $2$ is not in $\mathbb{4}\mathbb{Z}$. But $2\times 2$ *is* in $\mathbb{4}\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, $4\mathbb{Z}$ is not a prime ideal, since you can have a product where neither factor is in the ideal, but the product *is*.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: It is in *exact* analogy to a prime number: a prime number is a number that is not $1$, and whenever it divides a product, it must divide at least one of the factors: $p|ab\implies p|a\text{ or }p|b$. By contrast, for an arbitrary number you know that if $n|a$ then $n|ab$: if it divides one factor, then it divides the product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the former - inclusive not exclusive or. In math, we always use the inclusive or unless explicitly stated otherwise.

As a sanity check, your other definition doesn't really even make sense. Take an ideal $I \subseteq R$ that is "prime" per your second definition, and take $a, b \in I$. Then by definition of an ideal, $ab \in I$. But by this exclusive or definition, precisely one of $a, b$ can be in $I$. In other words, no ideals are "prime" per your second definition.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. site policy [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque Understood, I'll keep that in mind.